# gnuplot: Is there a way to plot vertical lines spatially?

Tags: plot, graph, gnuplot

I am trying to plot several vertical lines of a variable, say velocity (m/s), against a x-axis of distance (m) and a y-axis of height(m). Each of the velocity profiles come as a function of height measured at different locations. So the aim is to observe how these profiles change spatially.

I have thought to approach this by shifting the vertical profiles by the x-component corresponding to the location where each profile was measured. So if we suppose that the second x-axis depicts velocity I want it to reset to 0 at every point of measurement.

Sketch of desired outcome (ignoring black colour):
[image]

Does anyone have any idea of what the right course of action would be? I am using **gnuplot** but any alternatives are welcome. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Below you may have a look at the data I use (file *verProfiles* in the code snippet)

| z(m) | U_1(m/s)* | U_4(m/s)* | U_8(m/s)* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.50 | 1.66 | 1.82 | 1.95 |
| 0.75 | 1.85 | 2.04 | 2.11 |
| 1.00 | 2.00 | 2.20 | 2.18 |
| 1.25 | 2.12 | 2.34 | 2.21 |
| 1.50 | 2.23 | 2.36 | 2.22 |
| 1.75 | 2.33 | 2.37 | 2.22 |
| 2.00 | 2.41 | 2.38 | 2.22 |

*The numbers 1, 4 and 8 in the names of U variables in the table above denote the location where the measurements are taken hence each U profile should start and the respective x point in the graph.

The gnuplot code that I've written so far and generates a **false** graph is:

```
outName="U_test.png"

set terminal pngcairo font "helvetica,20" size 800, 1000
set xtics nomirror
set x2tics
set xrange [0:10] noreverse nowriteback
set autoscale x2fix
set yrange [0:2.5]
set grid
set mxtics 4
set mx2tics 4
set mytics 4
set key left top
set key samplen 2
set key spacing 0.75
set xlabel  "x"
set x2label "Ux [m s^{-1}]"
set ylabel "z"
set output "$outName"

inp0="verProfiles"

plot \
    inp0 u 2:1 t "U_1" axes x2y1 w lp ps 2 lw 2 lc rgb "#009E73", \
    inp0 u 3:1 t "U_4" axes x2y1 w lp ps 2 lw 2 lc rgb "#3F8B77", \
    inp0 u 4:1 t "U_8" axes x2y1 w lp ps 2 lw 2 lc rgb "#7EA99E"
```

The generated false graph is:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is difficult to make any suggestion if we don't know how your data format looks like. Please provide example data and in case you have some gnuplot code.

Comment: Hello, do you have the x components for each velocities and heights ?

Comment: Hi both and thanks for the interest. I edited my post based on @theozh comment. The x components of the velocity profiles are 1, 4 and 8 metres respectively but any abstract numbers should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your intention correctly, this would be my suggestion.
You want to offset your x-data by `1`,`4`, and `8`, so you have to add these values to your columns `$2`, `$3`, `$4`.
If I understood your sketch with 0 m/s correctly, you also want to subtract the first velocity value from it.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.
So, you take the pseudocolumn 0 (check `help pseudocolumns`), which is basically the line number starting from 0. If `$0==0` (check ternary operator `help ternary`) you assign the current value (only the first value) of your column to a variable, e.g. `xoff=$2`and subtract it from all following values in your column. Since you have a header you have to skip one line, i.e. `skip 1`.

In case you want several x-axes on top all starting from 0, this could be either done with arrows and labels or depending on what exactly you need maybe with multiplots (check `help multiplot`).

Check the following as starting point:

**Code:**

```
### plotting with different offsets
reset session

$Data <<EOD
z(m)  U_1(m/s)*  U_4(m/s)*  U_8(m/s)*
0.50       1.66       1.82       1.95
0.75       1.85       2.04       2.11
1.00       2.00       2.20       2.18
1.25       2.12       2.34       2.21
1.50       2.23       2.36       2.22
1.75       2.33       2.37       2.22
2.00       2.41       2.38       2.22
EOD

set xrange[0:10]
set xtics 1
set yrange [0.3:2.4]
set grid xtics, ytics

vs = "1 4 8"
set for [v in vs] arrow from v, graph 0 to v, graph 1 lw 1.5 lc "black" dt 2 nohead

plot $Data u ($0==0?xoff=$2:0, $2+1-xoff):1 skip 1 w lp ps 1.5 lw 2 pt 7 lc "red"   ti "U_1", \
     ''    u ($0==0?xoff=$3:0, $3+4-xoff):1 skip 1 w lp ps 1.5 lw 2 pt 7 lc "green" ti "U_4", \
     ''    u ($0==0?xoff=$4:0, $4+8-xoff):1 skip 1 w lp ps 1.5 lw 2 pt 7 lc "black" ti "U_8"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Maybe now I have a better idea about what you probably want.
I guess you "simply" want to have subplots at defined locations within a "Main"plot.
gnuplot offers the feature of `multiplot` (check `help multiplot`) which will place several plots next to or on top of each other.
You can define the origin (check `help origin`) and the size (check `help size`) of each subplot.
However, the coordinates and sizes of the subplots are given in screen coordinates.
The problem is now: how to place the plot at the desired location relative to the first plot?
With labels, arrows, and objects you can use screen, graph and axes coordinates (check `help coordinates`), but I am not aware that you can use axis coordinates of the previous plot.
So, you have to calculate these positions yourself using some internal gnuplot variables `GPVAL_...`. It looks complicated but is just some coordinate transformation.

**Code:**

```
### plotting with different offsets
reset session

$Data <<EOD
z(m)  U_1(m/s)*  U_4(m/s)*  U_8(m/s)*
0.50       1.66       1.82       1.95
0.75       1.85       2.04       2.11
1.00       2.00       2.20       2.18
1.25       2.12       2.34       2.21
1.50       2.23       2.36       2.22
1.75       2.33       2.37       2.22
2.00       2.41       2.38       2.22
EOD

set for [v in "1 4 8"] arrow from v, graph 0 to v, graph 1 lw 1.5 lc "black" dt 2 nohead

XFirstToGrphRel(x) = (x-MainXMin)/(MainXMax - MainXMin)   # relative position to graph 
YFirstToGrphRel(y) = (y-MainYMin)/(MainYMax - MainYMin)
PosX(x) = XminScrRel+GraphInScrSizeX*XFirstToGrphRel(x)   # screen positon of the subplot
PosY(y) = YminScrRel+GraphInScrSizeY*YFirstToGrphRel(y)
SizeX(dx) = GraphInScrSizeX*dx/(MainXMax - MainXMin)      # screen size of a subplot 
SizeY(dy) = GraphInScrSizeY*dy/(MainYMax - MainYMin)

set multiplot 

    set xlabel "x / m"
    set xrange[0:12]
    set xtics 1
    set ylabel "z / m"
    set yrange [0.3:2.4]
    set ytics 0.5
    set grid xtics, ytics

    plot 0 w p ps 0 notitle    # plot nothing, just background plot
    # store the current terminal values for later use
    MainXMin = GPVAL_X_MIN
    MainXMax = GPVAL_X_MAX
    MainYMin = GPVAL_Y_MIN
    MainYMax = GPVAL_Y_MAX
    GraphInScrSizeX = real(GPVAL_TERM_XMAX-GPVAL_TERM_XMIN)/GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE*GPVAL_TERM_SCALE  # real() to avoid integer division
    GraphInScrSizeY = real(GPVAL_TERM_YMAX-GPVAL_TERM_YMIN)/GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE*GPVAL_TERM_SCALE
    XminScrRel = real(GPVAL_TERM_XMIN)/GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE*GPVAL_TERM_SCALE   
    YminScrRel = real(GPVAL_TERM_YMIN)/GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE*GPVAL_TERM_SCALE

    unset arrow
    set margins 0,0,0,0
    unset xlabel
    unset xtics
    set x2label "v / m/s"
    set x2range [0:2.5]
    set x2tics 0.5 offset 0.5
    unset ylabel
    set format y ""
    set yrange [0.5:2.0]
    set grid x2tics, ytics
    
    set object 1 rect from graph 0, graph 0 to graph 1, graph 1 behind fc "white"
    set size SizeX(2),SizeY(1.5)

    set origin PosX(1),PosY(0.5)
    plot $Data u 2:1 axes x2y1 w lp pt 7 lc "red" notitle
    
    set origin PosX(4.0),PosY(0.5)
    plot $Data u 3:1 axes x2y1 w lp pt 7 lc "green" notitle
    
    set origin PosX(8.0),PosY(0.5)
    plot $Data u 4:1 axes x2y1 w lp pt 7 lc "blue" notitle
    
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting work around. The data provided do not match the sketch. The 0 value in the sketch suggests that the vertical dashed lines act as the origin of the velocity profiles. Thus, positive values are on the right-hand side of the dashed line while negative values lie on the left-hand side. I think that instead of substracting with the first value I can multiply each value with a scale factor in order to avoid big numbers (bigger than the max x component).

Comment: @petrosca I guess it might be better to use `multiplot` because as I understand you want aligned subplots in a "main"plot. See modified answer.

Comment: @petrosca a bit more generalized see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65640036/7295599